# Java/Hibernate HQL get rows from table queries returning null errors

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have created a simple HQL query which works to get the first ten rows from the database's table.  I can print out data from the list of objects just fine.

This code is invoked by **#{HomeController.results}** in the HTML.  The Log list is then passed back to the Home Controller class.

```
String queryString = "FROM Log";
Query query = entity.createQuery(queryString);
query.setMaxResults(10);

List<Log> results = query.getResultList();
```

Unfortunately whenever I try and do any other query that I thought would be simple, it freaks out and throws null pointers or out of bounds errors.

For example, to try and change the order of the list to get the last ten rows instead:

```
String queryString = "FROM Log ORDER BY batchId DESC";
```

Gives null pointer errors when html tries to access the first property (all rows have a batchId).

Or to try and get rows from this week:

```
String queryString = "FROM Log x WHERE to_char(x.logDate, 'WW/YYYY') = 
                     to_char(current_date, 'WW/YYYY')";
```

Gives index out of bounds for the first property too.  I must be doing something simple incorrectly and would like someone to explain the obvious.

EDIT UPON REQUEST:

HTML:

```
<!-- get table from database, returns size of results list -->
Results: <h:outputText value="#{homeController.results}" />

<br></br>
BatchId: <h:outputText value="#{homeController.batchId}" />
RecordId: <h:outputText value="#{homeController.recordId}" />
UnitName: <h:outputText value="#{homeController.unitName}" />
LogDate: <h:outputText value="#{homeController.logDate}" />
LogFlag: <h:outputText value="#{homeController.logFlag}" />
LogFields: <h:outputText value="#{homeController.logFields}" />
LogReason: <h:outputText value="#{homeController.logReason}" />
ProcessGroup: <h:outputText value="#{homeController.processGroup}" />
<!-- iterate next row -->
<h:outputText value="#{homeController.row}" />
```

Log Bean:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(Log.class)
@Audited
@Table(name = "log")
public class Log implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3258748209780261981L;
private Integer batchId;
private Integer recordId;
private String unitName;
private Date logDate;
private String logFlag;
private String logFields;
private String logReason;
private String processGroup;

// batchId AND processGroup is composite primary key!!
// equals and hashCode methods necessary for implementing composite key!
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((batchId == null) ? 0 : batchId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((processGroup == null) ? 0 : processGroup.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Log))
        return false;
    Log other = (Log) obj;
    if (batchId == null) {
        if (other.batchId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!batchId.equals(other.batchId))
        return false;
    if (processGroup == null) {
        if (other.processGroup != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!processGroup.equals(other.processGroup))
        return false;
    return true;
}


@Id
@Column(name = "BATCH_ID")
public Integer getBatchId() {
    return batchId;
}
public void setBatchId(Integer batch_id) {
    this.batchId = batch_id;
}

@Column(name = "RECORD_ID")
public Integer getRecordId() {
    return recordId;
}
public void setRecordId(Integer record_id) {
    this.recordId = record_id;
}

@Column(name = "UNIT_NAME")
public String getUnitName() {
    return unitName;
}
public void setUnitName(String unit_name) {
    this.unitName = unit_name;
}

@Column(name = "LOG_DATE")
public Date getLogDate() {
    return logDate;
}
public void setLogDate(Date log_date) {
    this.logDate = log_date;
}

@Column(name = "LOG_FLAG")
public String getLogFlag() {
    return logFlag;
}
public void setLogFlag(String log_flag) {
    this.logFlag = log_flag;
}

@Column(name = "LOG_FIELDS")
public String getLogFields() {
    return logFields;
}
public void setLogFields(String log_fields) {
    this.logFields = log_fields;
}

@Column(name = "LOG_REASON")
public String getLogReason() {
    return logReason;
}
public void setLogReason(String log_reason) {
    this.logReason = log_reason;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "PROCESSGROUP")
public String getProcessGroup() {
    return processGroup;
}
public void setProcessGroup(String processgroup) {
    this.processGroup = processgroup;
}

}
```

Home Controller:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped // must be properly scoped to maintain resultsList
public class HomeController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6700905317429809540L;
    private static List<Log> resultsList;
    private static Integer row = 0;

    private String message = "Hello World";
    private String  results = "NULL", 
                    batchId = "NULL", 
                    recordId = "NULL", 
                    unitName = "NULL", 
                    logDate = "NULL", 
                    logFlag = "NULL", 
                    logFields = "NULL", 
                    logReason = "NULL", 
                    processGroup = "NULL";

    @Inject
    ReferenceDataService referenceDataService;

    // retrieves rows from HubToBauExceptionLog from database and assigns to resultsList
    // return string of resultList size
    public String getResults()
    {
        setResults("");
        return results;
    }
    public void setResults(String input)
    {
        resultsList = referenceDataService.retrievePlantMappings();
        row  = 0; // reset row to start
        this.results = "" + resultsList.size();
    }

    // iterate and return row number from resultsList
    public String getRow()
    {
        setRow("");
        return "";
    }
    public void setRow(String input)
    {
        row++;
    }

    // returns batchId from current resultsList row
    public String getBatchId()
    {
        setBatchId("");
        return batchId;
    }
    public void setBatchId(String input)
    {
        if (resultsList.get(row).getBatchId() != null)
        {
            this.batchId =  resultsList.get(row).getBatchId().toString();
        }
    }

    // returns recordId from current resultsList row
    public String getRecordId()
    {
        setRecordId("");
        return recordId;
    }
    public void setRecordId(String input)
    {
        if (resultsList.get(row).getRecordId() != null)
        {
            this.recordId = resultsList.get(row).getRecordId().toString();
        }
    }

    // returns unitName from current resultsList row
    public String getUnitName()
    {
        setUnitName("");
        return unitName;
    }
    public void setUnitName(String input)
    {
        if (resultsList.get(row).getUnitName() != null)
        {
            this.unitName = resultsList.get(row).getUnitName().toString();
        }
    }

    // returns logDate from current resultsList row
    public String getLogDate()
    {
        setLogDate("");
        return logDate;
    }
    public void setLogDate(String input)
    {
        if (resultsList.get(row).getLogDate() != null)
        {
            this.logDate = resultsList.get(row).getLogDate().toString();
        }
    }

    // returns logFlag from current resultsList row
    public String getLogFlag()
    {
        setLogFlag("");
        return logFlag;
    }
    public void setLogFlag(String input)
    {
        if (resultsList.get(row).getLogFlag() != null)
        {
            this.logFlag = resultsList.get(row).getLogFlag().toString();
        }
    }

    // returns logFields from current resultsList row
    public String getLogFields()
    {
        setLogFields("");
        return logFields;
    }
    public void setLogFields(String input)
    {
        if (resultsList.get(row).getLogFields() != null)
        {
            this.logFields = resultsList.get(row).getLogFields().toString();
        }
    }

    // returns logReason from current resultsList row
    public String getLogReason()
    {
        setLogReason("");
        return logReason;
    }
    public void setLogReason(String input)
    {
        if (resultsList.get(row).getLogReason() != null)
        {
            this.logReason = resultsList.get(row).getLogReason().toString();
        }
    }

    // returns processGroup from current resultsList row
    public String getProcessGroup()
    {
        setProcessGroup("");
        return processGroup;
    }
    public void setProcessGroup(String input)
    {
        if (resultsList.get(row).getProcessGroup() != null)
        {
            this.processGroup = resultsList.get(row).getProcessGroup().toString();
        }
    }

}
```

Error Output:

```
17:00:30,502 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "x.war"
17:00:30,502 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "xx.war"
17:00:30,502 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."x.war".component.databaseMigrator.START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."x.war".component.databaseMigrator.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance

17:00:30,596 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
17:00:30,596 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015954: Admin console is not enabled
17:00:30,596 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.0.1.GA (AS 7.1.3.Final-redhat-4) started (with errors) in 21869ms - Started 1294 of 1383 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 84 services are passive or on-demand)
17:00:32,049 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Error Rendering View[/views/home.xhtml]: javax.el.ELException: /views/home.xhtml @37,66 value="#{homeController.batchId}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:88) [primefaces-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:71) [primefaces-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeContent(FieldsetRenderer.java:94) [primefaces-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeMarkup(FieldsetRenderer.java:76) [primefaces-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeEnd(FieldsetRenderer.java:47) [primefaces-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100) [primefaces-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:307) [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at xx.controller.HomeController.setBatchId(HomeController.java:70) [classes:]
    at xx.controller.HomeController.getBatchId(HomeController.java:65) [classes:]
    at xx.controller.HomeController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getBatchId(HomeController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302) [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 54 more

17:00:32,066 SEVERE [org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) null: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at xx.controller.HomeController.setBatchId(HomeController.java:70) [classes:]
    at xx.controller.HomeController.getBatchId(HomeController.java:65) [classes:]
    at xx.controller.HomeController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getBatchId(HomeController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302) [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:88) [primefaces-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:71) [primefaces-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeContent(FieldsetRenderer.java:94) [primefaces-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeMarkup(FieldsetRenderer.java:76) [primefaces-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeEnd(FieldsetRenderer.java:47) [primefaces-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100) [primefaces-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
```

Comment: No code, no stack trace, how could we help? You seem to think HQL is the same thing as SQL. It's not. to_char is an SQL function, not an HQL function. Read the JPQL and HQL chapter of the user manual.

Comment: Well you already did help by mentioning that to_char is SQL only!  Added code and error trace now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing logic that sets the batchId, recordId etc properties on your Bean with values that you retrieved from your query. Where is the query executed? It looks like there's some missing logic. Your properties on your bean are never set values with results from the query, and it looks like your query is never executed.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to define the relationship between the first code calling the result list and it then being transfered to the home controller class.  That happens in the "results" calling in the HTML.  I've edited the question.

Comment: If getResults() is called, it's currently setting results to "". Are there other changes/updates you've made since?

Comment: Not that I can think?  Are you saying there has to be something else I've done to explain it?  When I switch back to the query "FROM Log" it runs fine and prints out the top ten rows perfectly, but whenever I try something simple like trying to list from bottom to top it just prints out various null pointer errors.